# Reload time & retries in selenium for a url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium with python for downloading file from a url.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
        try:
        browser.get("http://www.drugcite.com/?q=ACTIMMUNE")
        browser.find_element

        browser.find_element_by_id('exportpt').click()
        browser.find_element_by_id('exporthlgt').click()
    except:
        pass
```

I want to set timeout for this program. Means, If within 60 seconds if this url is not loaded due to net issue, it should retry after each 60 seconds and after 3 tries, it should go ahead.

How can I achieve such in this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use **browser.implicitly_wait(60)**

[WebDriver.implicitly_wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.implicitly_wait)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in to do this. However, I wouldn't have said it would be too hard.

Just use an [explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to find a particular element *that should* be there when the page loads. Set the timeout to be 60 seconds on this explicit wait.

Wrap this in a loop that executes up to three times. To avoid it running three times unnecessarily, put in a [break](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm) statement when the explicit wait actually runs without any issue.

That means it'll run up to three times, waiting 60 seconds a time, and once it's successful it'll exit the loop. If it isn't successful after *all of that*, then it'll crash.

Note: I've not *actually* tried this but it's just a logical solution!